# Using the CAST or CONVERT clause multiple times on the same SQL line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and i thank you for your patience

I have this code

```
SELECT
    ProductName,
    ListPrice,
    DiscountPercent,
    CAST(ListPrice as decimal)Cast(DiscountPercent as decimal)(1-DiscountPercent/100.0)
FROM Products
```

I am needing the code to select the three columns, then in the fourth column to convert to decimal, and apply the discount to the listPrice and print it into the same column.

Forgive me if this has been answered I am still learning syntax and couldn't find what I was looking for.

I understand that there might be a simpler way and very open to hearing how to do it. I appreciate any input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compute here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a multiplication.

```
SELECT productname,
       listprice,
       discountpercent,
       cast(listprice AS decimal) * (1 - cast(discountpercent AS decimal) / 100.0)
       FROM products;
```

Though it is  advisable to change the schema in a way that the columns already have the right data type.

Comment: Thank you for this @Sticky Bit , could you explain what you mean by Shcema? Please and thank you!

Comment: @KolemanParsley: By schema I mean the design of the database. How the tables are defined etc.. In particular here I mean the data types of the columns of the table.